# Javascript - Stop at Footer Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using some Javascript to get an element to stop when it arrives at a specific div. The Javascript using an amount of pixels from the bottom of the page.

I want to change that so it stops when it reaches a specific div class. In the case of my JSFiddle below, to stop when it reaches the Footer div.

I changed this:

```
var bottomBound = 500
```

to this:

```
var bottomBound = $('.stopper').css();
```

But it doesn't seem to like my solution. It won't work.

Here is the JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/phostercreative/1y1y34y2/

Thanks in advance!
Brian

Comment: What do you mean you want to stop before the bottom of the page? Do you just want the div to not go all the way to the bottom of the page?  Shouldn't that be a simple (and purely) CSS problem?  I don't understand what JS has to do with this?

Comment: I want it to hover in the lower right corner of the user's viewport. Once they scroll down to the footer, I want it to stop scrolling with the user (staying put, above the footer)

Comment: Try `var bottomBound = $('.stopper').offset().top;` - This will get you the distance from the top. If you need the distance from the bottom, subtract this value from your document height.

Comment: Thanks Santi. I am a Javascript Novice. How do I subtract that value from the document height?

Comment: `var bottomBound = $(document).height() - $('.stopper').offset().top;`